# How to dynamically grab the first field of each table tr with jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to separate the names and schedules of this table to store in the database, verifying that already contains some data in the field or not.

```
<table class="linha-horas">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th><h5>Profipo p/ Itaum</h5></th>
   <th><h5>Itaum p/ Ulysses G</h5></th>
   <th><h5>Ulysses G. p/ Itaum</h5></th>
   <th><h5>Itaum p/ Profipo</h5></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12:49</td>
   <td>05:46</td>
   <td>05:55</td>
   <td>06:08</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>18:05</td>
   <td>13:12</td>
   <td>06:31</td>
   <td>06:44</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="empty"></td>
   <td>18:29</td>
   <td>11:01</td>
   <td>11:14</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

An example of the result I want:

```
Profipo p/ Itaum
12:49
18:05

Itaum p/ Ulysses G
05:46
13:12
18:29
```

and dynamically so if the table contains more schedules...

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tip is to use **:eq()** in **select**, please find below the code:

```
public final static String stack = "<table class=\"linha-horas\">"
 +"<tbody><tr><th><h5>Profipo p/ Itaum</h5></th><th><h5>Itaum p/ Ulysses G</h5>"
 + "</th><th><h5>Ulysses G. p/ Itaum</h5></th><th><h5>Itaum p/ Profipo</h5></th></tr>"
 + "<tr><td>12:49</td><td>05:46</td><td>05:55</td><td>06:08</td></tr>"
 + "<tr><td>18:05</td><td>13:12</td><td>06:31</td><td>06:44</td></tr>"
 + "<tr><td class=\"empty\"></td><td>18:29</td><td>11:01</td><td>11:14</td></tr>"
 + "</tbody></table>";

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("the html content to parse is: "+stack);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(stack);
    Elements ths = doc.select("th");
    for(int i = 0; i < ths.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ths.get(i).text());//header
        Elements tds = doc.select("tr td:eq("+i+")");//rows
        for(Element td : tds)
        {
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    }
}
```

and following is the output:

```
the html content to parse is: <table class="linha-horas"><tbody><tr><th><h5>Profipo p/ Itaum</h5></th><th><h5>Itaum p/ Ulysses G</h5></th><th><h5>Ulysses G. p/ Itaum</h5></th><th><h5>Itaum p/ Profipo</h5></th></tr><tr><td>12:49</td><td>05:46</td><td>05:55</td><td>06:08</td></tr><tr><td>18:05</td><td>13:12</td><td>06:31</td><td>06:44</td></tr><tr><td class="empty"></td><td>18:29</td><td>11:01</td><td>11:14</td></tr></tbody></table>
Profipo p/ Itaum
12:49
18:05

Itaum p/ Ulysses G
05:46
13:12
18:29
Ulysses G. p/ Itaum
05:55
06:31
11:01
Itaum p/ Profipo
06:08
06:44
11:14
```